# Use \r, \n in OGNL expression in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, ognl

I'm using XML based Java Spring DSL for Camel routes and need to do a very simple replace in a string. Normally it works ok with an OGNL expression. But if i use special characters like \r or \n - it fails to be executed as java expression.
Example which doesn't work:

```
<setBody>
    <simple>${body.replace("\n","\r\n")}</simple>
</setBody>
```

Any ideas how to pass these chars to the java in a correct way ?

Camel version is 2.12, just in case.

Comment: `it fails to be executed as java expression` What do you mean? Is there any error? Do you get any exception?

Comment: I mean that when simple lannguage parser parses this expression and tries to execute as java String.replace method - it fails with exception. I'll try to attach it a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

I have currently implemented this type of logic in a sample program I made earlier like below:

```
from("source location")
    .setBody(body().regexReplaceAll("\r", ""))
    .to("a cool place");
```

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. The problem is when you do this in XML. In Java DSL it works ok for me too.

Comment: For the XML I believe you are missing escape characters for the quotes